# Write breakline in HTML from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) code that does some stuff, but at some point I need to do this:

```
$('#mySpan').text('Hello\nWorld');
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<span id="mySpan"></span>
```

So I can finally get this:

Hello
World

The problem is that HTML is not detecting the breakline inserted from the JavaScript. I also tried this:

```
$('#mySpan').text('Hello<BR/>World');
```

But it doesn't work either.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$('#mySpan').html('Hello<br/>World');
```

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
$('#mySpan').html('Hello<br/>World');
```

?

[text](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) only sets the text contents whereas [html](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) sets the HTML contents.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use try this initially on:

```
$('#mySpan').html('Hello<br />World');
```

Comment: I wonder what is wrong with above code, why down voting after i have corrected it?????????

Comment: can any one who down votes explain his point please so that i could learn from them probably. thanks

Comment: Sorry Sarfraz, I didn't see your post until I already marked resolved with the previous post, I don't know why you have that -1 ??? I'm new at the forum so I don't know well the rules yet. But thanks for your reply, it was also the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [`.append()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append) instead of `.text()`, if should break the line with your `<br />` properly.